# EF Code First Database Not Generated using MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I'm developing an app using EF Code First and MVC3. The solution contains three pprojects; **ProjectName.Model** involving **POCO** classes only, **ProjectName.App** involving **MVC3** web project from that the default Model folder (created by MVC itself) is removed from, and **ProjectName.Repository** that is containing a **generic repository, UnitOfWork, plus DatabaseContext classes**.
The **problem** is that, the EF5 generates the Database but with no tables included:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext() : base("name=MahalehMaDB") { }
    //
    public DbSet<Man> Mans { get; set; }
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RoleGroup> RoleGroups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ServiceRole> ServiceRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ServiceDetails> ServiceDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ActionProvider> ActionProviders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RoleGroupUser> RoleGroupUsers { get; set; }
    //
    public static void InitializeDatabase()
    {
        using (DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DatabaseContext, Configuration>());
        }
    }
}

<connectionStrings>
<add name="MahalehMaDB"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MahalehDatabase;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And I'm confused what might be preventing the EF5 from generating the Database with its tables.
Note that, the **InitializeDatabase** method is called in the Application_Start method of Global.asax file. Is there something wrong with the InitializeDatabase method? Controller classes are also implemented incomplete, Could it be the caues? I've been surfing the web so much but couldn't handle it, thus decided to come here!

Does anyone have any idea to handle the problem? Please let me know if the information isn't enough.

Kindly appreciate...

Comment: I think your Data Source property of connection string might not be ok. Please check it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:    `public DatabaseContext() : base("MahalehMaDB") { }`

This code is invalid value for connection string name: `base("name:MahalehMaDB") { }`

Comment: @user2394196 .\SQLEXPRESS is this ok?

Comment: Yes, it is. By the way, my name is Ali, Persian too?

Comment: Yes please check your connection string i thnik your coonection string has problem

Comment: I think your code is correct but when u use this:MahalehMaDB in constructor you should use same name for connection string

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30619/discussion-between-shahrooz-jefri--and-user2394196)

Answer (score 0):

```
public Context(): base("MahalehMaDB"){ }
```

And in web.config:

```
<add name="MahalehMaDB" connectionString="Data Source=yourservername;
  InitialCatalog=database;
  Integrated Security=true"providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```